# Installing style50

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, cs50

I have been trying to install `style50` which is a python package and it is or of the command-line tools for CS50.

I have tried severally, and I keep getting the following errors. Can anyone help me check through?

```
muyiwa@muyiwa-HP-Pro-3010-Microtower-PC:~$ python -m pip install --user style50
Collecting style50
  Using cached style50-2.7.5-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2>=2.10 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from style50) (3.0.1)
Collecting icdiff
  Using cached icdiff-2.0.4.tar.gz (16 kB)
Collecting argparse
  Downloading argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from style50) (1.1.0)
Collecting autopep8>=1.4.3
  Downloading autopep8-1.5.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (45 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 45 kB 2.9 kB/s 
Collecting python-magic
  Using cached python_magic-0.4.24-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting jsbeautifier
  Using cached jsbeautifier-1.14.0.tar.gz (73 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 2:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-y09aan4z/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (56 lines):
  Collecting setuptools>=40.8.0
    Downloading setuptools-58.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (816 kB)
  ERROR: Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.25.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 425, in _error_catcher
      yield
    File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.25.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 507, in read
      data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
    File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.12.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
      data = self.__fp.read(amt)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 455, in read
      n = self.readinto(b)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 499, in readinto
      n = self.fp.readinto(b)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
      return self._sock.recv_into(b)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
      return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
      return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  socket.timeout: The read operation timed out
  
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 186, in _main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 357, in run
      resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 177, in resolve
      discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 333, in _resolve_one
      abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 282, in _get_abstract_dist_for
      abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 480, in prepare_linked_requirement
      local_path = unpack_url(
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 282, in unpack_url
      return unpack_http_url(
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 158, in unpack_http_url
      from_path, content_type = _download_http_url(
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 303, in _download_http_url
      for chunk in download.chunks:
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/ui.py", line 160, in iter
      for x in it:
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/utils.py", line 15, in response_chunks
      for chunk in response.raw.stream(
    File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.25.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 564, in stream
      data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
    File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.25.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 529, in read
      raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
      self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
    File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.25.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 430, in _error_catcher
      raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
  urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 2: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-y09aan4z/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: error shows problem with `jsbeautifier` which has problem with `setuptools`. Maybe you have to update `setuptools` or install `wheel` or maybe you have to update C/C++ library `SSL` which also shows in error.

Comment: pypi style50 https://pypi.org/project/style50/#files ... says "Programming Language, python:: **3**" . ........ Example, build : `cd style50-2.7.5/ && python3 setup.py build` : No errors.